# How do I get HTML email content before sending in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I want to replace all links in the HTML email with tracker. As far as I know there is this `EVENT_BEFORE_SEND` event. So I created some behavior that can be used like below

```
$mailer = \Yii::$app->mailer;
/* @var $mailer \yii\mail\BaseMailer */
$mailer->attachBehavior('archiver', [
   'class' => \app\MailTracker::class
]);
```

Here's the content of the `MyTracker` class.

```
class MailTracker extends Behavior {
    public function events() {
        return [
            \yii\mail\BaseMailer::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND => 'trackMail',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param \yii\mail\MailEvent $event
     */
     public function trackMail($event) {
        $message = $event->message;

        $htmlOutput = $this->how_do_i_get_the_html_output();
        $changedOutput = $this->changeLinkWithTracker($htmlOutput);
        $message->getHtmlBody($changedOutput);
     }
}
```

The problem now is `\yii\mail\BaseMailer` doesn't provide method to get the HTML output rendered before sending.

How to do this?

**UPDATE**

The only way I can get this is through this hacky way.

```
    /* @var $message \yii\swiftmailer\Message */
    if ($message instanceof \yii\swiftmailer\Message) {
        $swiftMessage = $message->getSwiftMessage();
        $r = new \ReflectionObject($swiftMessage);
        $parentClassThatHasBody = $r->getParentClass()
                ->getParentClass()
                ->getParentClass(); //\Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity
        $body = $parentClassThatHasBody->getProperty('_immediateChildren');
        $body->setAccessible(true);
        $children = $body->getValue($swiftMessage);
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($child instanceof \Swift_MimePart &&
                    $child->getContentType() == 'text/html') {
                $html = $child->getBody();
                break;
            }
        }
        print_r($html);
    }
```

Comment: I've ended up having to do the same thing. Very frustrating.

Comment: To avoid using Reflection, I've managed to get the mail body (without encoding) by calling `$message->getChildren()[0]->getBody()`

Answer (score 9):

One approach that I've found is to use `render()` instead of `compose()`.
So we need to render the message string before sending and then compose it again.

```
$string = Yii::$app->mailer->render('path/to/view', ['params' => 'foo'], 'path/to/layout');
```

Yii doc:
[yii\mail\BaseMailer::render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mail-basemailer.html#render()-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to edit your email content, you can try editor in view with ckeditor . Ckeditor helps you to edit the contents as you desire.

https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget

Edit the contents before sending email.

Answer (score 0):

I created a workaround with preg_match and substitutions, in case is helpful for anyone.

```
$message = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose('templateName', ['data' => $data])->toString();
// Workaround cause Swift_Mailer doesn't have getBody()
preg_match("/<body>(.*)<\/body>/si", $message, $matches);
$delimitedHtmlBody = $matches[1];
$htmlBody = str_replace("=\r\n", '', $delimitedHtmlBody);
$htmlBody = str_replace("=3D", '=', $htmlBody);
```